# dokku-mongo Export Database Error

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.6

dokku-mongo export Database command is showing error "This does not look like a tar archive"

```
$ ssh svuser@dbexample.com
$ dokku mongo:export database > backup.tar
$ tar -xfv backup.tar
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ ssh svuser@dbexample.com
$ dokku mongo:export database > backup.tar
$ tar -xfv backup.tar
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

As per `github dukku-mongodb` documentation by `@josegonzalez` [here](https://github.com/dokku/dokku-mongo/issues/105) I don't think the export is actually a tar. The readme we have is wrong, but if you run `dokku mongo:help export`, you'll see the correct usage.

Here's what `dokku mongo:help export` says:

```
export a dump of the MongoDB service database

arguments:

service   service to run command against

examples:
by default, datastore output is exported to stdout

dokku mongo:export lolipop

you can redirect this output to a file

dokku mongo:export lolipop > lolipop.dump

export a dump of the MongoDB service database
arguments:

service   service to run command against

examples:
by default, datastore output is exported to stdout

dokku mongo:export lolipop

you can redirect this output to a file

dokku mongo:export lolipop > lolipop.dump
```

For further your ref [here](https://github.com/dokku/dokku-mongo)